# Elastic Beanstalk Suspended state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created and deployed a Node.js application on Elastic Beanstalk using the CLI and my key pair. It was working fine yesterday, the application is live and functioning. I was also able to update it and deploy without any issues.

I only had a warning message:

> The environment health transitioned from "Pending" to "Warning." Initialization completed 11 seconds ago and took 3 minutes. Unable to assume the role "arn:aws:iam::387726373049:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role". Please verify that the role exists and is configured correctly.

This role does exist, and it has the following permissions:
[image]

With a trust policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

The next day, my application is now in State: Suspended.

And i have a Error message :

> Failed to deploy configuration.
> Failed to check health. Verify the permissions on the environment's service role and try again later. Permissions changes take up to two hours to propagate.

With CLI

```
❯ eb deploy
Creating application version archive "app-2765-230711_085546971343".
Uploading api-meeting-dev/app-2765-230711_085546971343.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2023-07-11 06:55:48    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2023-07-11 06:55:50    ERROR   Failed to check health. Verify the permissions on the environment's service role and try again later. Permissions changes take up to two hours to propagate.
2023-07-11 06:55:51    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

In environement-name>Configuration>Service access
I tried to change the IAM role and key pair, and when I save, I receive a success message. However, my modifications are not being applied.
[image]

My aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
[image]

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have encountered the exact same problem twice now. Since I couldn't find a solution the first time, I created another Elastic Beanstalk environment, but it seems that it didn't resolve the issue.

--EDIT :
i have change the check health to basic and that work but my state stay to "Grey"

Comment: For service role, please keep `elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com` as service and for instance profile policy, please keep `ec2.amazonaws.com` as service.

Comment: Somehow Elastic Beanstalk is not able to assume the service role `aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role`.

Comment: Please keep only these two managed service role policies for service role:- AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth, AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy.

Comment: Still, getting Unable to assume the role error? Maybe try creating duplicate service roles and instance profiles with different names other than default names and use them while creating the environment. Although the default names are working fine for me.

Comment: @ThomasM Did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: Hey Thomas, Any updates on this issue?
Facing the same problem

Comment: I am also facing the same issue right now. One of my application worked with exactly the same configurations but my second and third application which also uses the same roles is Suspended. Although the web-app got created correctly and is working fine, I mean the browser is showing the application correctly. Not sure where is problem with elastic beanstalk.